# how to resolve failed to create chrome process error in selenium-webdriver in JS

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

- i am trying to automate test with selenium web driver with jest
- chrome run as admin checkbox is also not checked in properties

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    
    driver =  await new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser(webdriver.Browser.CHROME)
    .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().setChromeBinaryPath('C:\\Application\\'))
    .build();
    await driver.getSession().then(()=> {
      sessionId = session.id_;
    })
    await driver.get('http://localhost:3000')
  })
```

the error i am getting is

> WebDriverError: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process.
> >>(Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)
> at Object.checkLegacyResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:558:15)

I need help on this i am new to selenium webdriver testing

Comment: Is that a valid binary path?

Comment: yeah the full path was necessary to chrome.exe